# Specified method is not supported in Aspx Web Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I have a `ASPxGridView` and I am using its delete confirmation like:

```
grdList.SettingsBehavior.ConfirmDelete = true;

grdList.SettingsText.ConfirmDelete = "Record will be deleted. Do you want to continue?";
```

When the customer hits the delete button

> "Specified method is not supported"

is throwed. When I test the page, its works how it should be.

Do you have any idea of what may cause that error? We both use IE.

Thank you.

Comment: A guess. If customer testing and your testing is on different environments, it is possible that they are out of  sync.

Answer (score 0):

*Specified method is not supported* thrown when deleting `ASPxGridView` row usually indicates that the corresponding command is not specified when the grid control tries to execute delete command against underlying data source. If you're using custom data source, take note to this explanation:

> When binding ASPxGridView with custom/non-declarative data sources,
>   **they may not have implemented the CRUD operations logic** (i.e., there
>   are no rules that describe how to automatically update a particular
>   item).

To fix this issue, you can handle `RowDeleting` event and set `Cancel` property to true to cancel updating operation as follows:

```
protected void grdList_RowDeleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as ASPxGridView;

    // make sure Cancel property set to true
    e.Cancel = true;

    // row deleting code here

    // data rebinding code here

    grdList.DataBind();
}
```

Note that `Cancel` property should **always** be set to `true`, either in `finally` block or before any part of code which potentially raise exception.

```
protected void grdList_RowDeleting(object sender, DevExpress.Web.Data.ASPxDataDeletingEventArgs e)
{
    var grid = sender as ASPxGridView;

    try 
    {
        // row deleting code here

        // data rebinding code here

        grdList.DataBind();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // exception handling
    }
    finally
    {
        // make sure Cancel property set to true
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

Additional references:

[Specified method is not supported on deleting GridView row](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q273982/specified-method-is-not-supported-on-deleting-gridview-row)

[How to implement CRUD operations with a custom data source](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA18686/aspxgridview-how-to-implement-crud-operations-with-a-custom-data-source)